# Looking for a continuous sliding carousel for Vue

Tags: vue.js, plugins, carousel

I'm looking for a Vue carousel where slides scroll automatically at a certain fixed speed from right to left. I still want the ability to stop the carousel from moving while hovering over it and of course the ability to drag the slides.

I'm searching for hours and even on https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#carousel there isn't even 1 carousel that keeps scrolling at 1 certain velocity. There's always an interval between the slides...

Comment: Did you try using this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick ?

Answer (score 0):

The component/interaction you seem to be looking for is called a "marquee".

Here's one I'm going to try myself: https://vue-marquee.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).